# P5.JS Sketch Won't Load in Browser

Tags: browser, loading, p5.js

I have a simple program, but I have an issue. I previously had a problem with the page displaying "Loading..." before, but I fixed that. Whenever I try to load now, I get "localhost refused to connect". I have tried the internet but all the fixes seem to be for the first error. How do I get it to load? Here is the code:

```
let pew;
let crosshair;
let imgConst = 100;
var imgSize = imgConst;
var imgChange = [4, (6 + 2/3), 10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20, (-33 - 1/3), -50];
for(var i = 0; i = imgChange.length; i++) {
  imgChange[i] = imgSize + imgConst/imgChange[i]
  console.log(i)
}
function preload() {
  crosshair = loadImage('crosshair.png')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  frameRate(10);
    noStroke();
    noCursor();
    pew = new bullet();
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 89, 100);
    //Shrink bullets
    pew.shrink()
    
    //crosshair
    image(crosshair, mouseX - imgSize/2, mouseY - imgSize/2, imgSize, imgSize);
}

// bullet class
class bullet {
  constructor() {
    this.x = [];
        this.y = [];
        this.size = [];
        this.shrinkSpeed = 1;
        this.diameter = 10;
  }

  shrink() {
        fill(61, 41, 15)
        for(var i = 0; i < this.x.length; i++) {
            if(this.size[i] <= 1) {
                this.size.splice(i);
            } else {
                ellipse(this.x[i], this.y[i], this.size[i], this.size[i]);
                this.size[i] = this.size[i] - this.shrinkSpeed;
            }
        }
  }
    add() {
        this.x.push(mouseX);
        this.y.push(mouseY);
        this.size.push(this.diameter)
        for( i = 0; i < imgChange.length * 1; i ++) {
          imgSize = imgChange[floor(i)]
          console.log(imgSize);
        }
    }
}

function mousePressed() {
  //add bullet
    pew.add();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in for loops.

First, in your first for loop, change `i = imgChange.length` to `i < imgChange.length`. Second, you are missing a `var` in the `add()` function of your bullet class: `for( i = 0`.

Now, your code should run.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, so I decided to just copy my code from my question but change what you said, and now it doesn't work... This exact code worked before.

Comment: Please copy the code from [here](https://pastebin.com/jYG7SFL8) just to be sure.
If this still doesn't work, there should be an error message in the console (CTRL + SHIFT + J if you are not using the web editor).
Please also make sure that your image (crosshair.png) is in the same folder as your sketch

Comment: (I copied the code before all this) Okay, so something interesting is happening: I checked the console, and it says the image couldn't be found because I forgot that I changed the file location, so I fixed the code, but now, it won't even load and gives no error message once it gives up.